# How to run Gemfire query for LocalDate?

Tags: date, gemfire, oql

```
public class Employee {
 private String name; 
 private LocalDate createdDate; //format yyyy-MM-dd
}
```

I tried following doesn't work. It says No Data Found. Also how can we do before, between, after queries using the date?

```
select * from /message where createdDate = to_date('2021-11-29', 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TO_DATE` I believe creates a `java.util.Date`, which I don't think is directly comparable to a `LocalDate`.

If you are invoking a query from the java API, you could construct a LocalDate and pass it in as a bind parameter. If you do that could should be able to use comparison operators like ">" or "<" to compare the dates, because those will invoke the java compareTo function. For example

```
queryService.newQuery("select * from /message where createdDate < $1", LocalDate.parse("2021-11-29"))
```

You might also consider storing a `java.util.Date` instead of a LocalDate on your object.

Comment: apologies for late reply. Now have stored java.util.Date as part of my object, which stores a date e.g. 2021-12-07T12:09:44.886+0000. It does the job. I can do select * from /message where createdDate > to_date ('2021-12-06', 'yyyy-MM-dd'). Thank you.